# No me deja iterar sobre un array despues de agarrar datos de un APi JavaScript-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

despues de buscar datos en un API intento buscar mas datos en la misma funcion ya que es necesaria una "key" de la anterior busqueda, despues de encontrar los datos utilizo useSelector para despues utilizarlo en un componente de react.

```
const getForecastAction = (location) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const listlocation = await apiService.getLocationKey(location);
    const listForecast = [];
    listlocation.data.forEach(async (data) => {
      const weather = await apiService.getForecast(data.Key);
      listForecast.push(weather.data);
    });
    console.log(listForecast);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_FORECAST,
      forecast: listForecast,
      location: listlocation.data,
    });
    return Promise.resolve([listForecast]);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

el listForecast deberia de retornar un array para despues utilizarlo, el cual si lo da pero de manera incompleto ya que al utilizarlo en un console.log() me devuelve un array con items pero no me deja iterar ni acceder a ellos

Comment: En qué momento no te deja usarlo?

Comment: No se puede utilizar un await dentro de un forEach este no espera, debes utilizar un loop más moderno por ejemplo  (for of), también podrías tener algún tema de ciclos de vida. Pero comenzaría por ese cambio.

Comment: muchas gracias, hare esos cambios mas adelante ya que acabe los usos del api el dia de hoy mas tarde hare sus propuestas.

Comment: y con respecto en donde no me deja utilizarlos es en el componente al usar useSelector, en esa funcion returno dos objetos el que da problemas es el forecastList mientras que las locaciones funciona perfectamente.

Comment: I managed to do it after noticing that the for...of the loop was not working since I had a liner error. then I decided to use another loop as suggested before. with the map loop, it was easier since that actually helped me reduce the lines of code I needed. after that with the list of promises I used `await Promises.all()` then everything was working as expected.

Comment: muchas gracias me gustaria poner la respuesta pero no se como.